# How to install NVIDIA graphics driver on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, driver, nvidia, display

How do I install a graphics driver on a virtual machine? I want to create a VM for gaming purposes and I cannot seem to get a graphics driver installed. I followed these guides:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/n-series-driver-setup
https://medium.com/azure-cloud/a-killer-guide-for-cloud-gaming-on-azure-march-2020-1aa56d13fba3

which all works fine until the download/setup of the graphics driver. Once the NVIDIA installation box pops up he says the machine is not suitable. I tried many different sizes of VM (NV6-8 series) to see if it was in system settings but nothing seems to work. Can someone provide help/insights? I just started my programming/Azure VM journey so assume I am a noob.

Answer (score 1):

Under advanced settings during the setup of a VM, you can click on 'select an extension to install' which will give the option to install an NVIDIA driver (among others).

[image: Install Extension VM]

Comment: This is to add an extension via UI and my reply is to add the extension with the PowerShell command. It works the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can install NVIDIA GPU drivers on N-series VMs running Windows with [NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/hpccompute-gpu-windows) or install NVIDIA GPU drivers manually.

In my example, I deployed a window server 2019 datacenter with a size `NC6` and Standard SSD Azure VM in the EastUs region.

[image]

Then installs NVIDIA GPU drivers with extension in PowerShell.

```
Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -VMName "myVm" -Location "East US"   -Publisher "Microsoft.HpcCompute" -ExtensionName "NvidiaGpuDriverWindows" -ExtensionType "NvidiaGpuDriverWindows" -TypeHandlerVersion 1.3
```

Finally, wait for a few moments to finish the extension, verify driver installation in Device Manager.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Nancy Xiong, much appreciated! I will try that next time; I managed to install an NVIDIA extension during the setup of the VM by using the 'install extension' option under the advanced settings. Nonetheless your answer should be helpful for others as well, thanks again.

Comment: Could you consider accepting this answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?